# Angular $resource and webApi

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am using webApi and have generated the model using entityframework the overload method of the GET(int id) I am trying to call that using the query of the `$resource`

I am trying to pass an optional parameter to a call using the `$resource` but get the error `[$resource:badcfg]` I have had a google and people say add

```
{
  'get': {method: 'GET'},
  'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
}
```

into the function, so I have tried this: but still have no luck.

```
function minorResource($resource, appSettings) {
    return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/minorworks/:id",
        {
            'get': {method: 'GET'},
            'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
        });
}
```

Would you use 2 separate methods or can the above function be made to work?

For completness here is my Controller call

```
minorResource.query({id: vm.seachCriteria}, function (data) {
        //console.log(data);
        vm.minorWork = data;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that query is used to retrieve an **array** of objects and get is used to retrieve a **single** object. That means that with a get you usually sent the id of the object to the API.

So in your case:

```
var minorWorksResource = $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/minorworks/:id");
// Note that query returns an array.
var works = minorWorksResource.query(function() {
    var firstWork = works[0];
});
// Note that we pass an ID that will be fetched in the query string.
var singleWork = minorWorksResource.get({id: 123}, function() {

});
```

And the WebAPI part:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/minorworks")]
public class MinorWorksController : ApiController {
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id) {
         var singleWork = null;
         // Retrieve a single item;
         return Ok(singleWork);
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Get() {
         var workList = null;
         // Retrieve the whole list.
         return Ok(workList );
    }
}
```